# How to enable MouseTimeDisplay on mobiles?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, video.js

On mobile devices, the component MouseTimeDisplay is disabled by default. MouseTimeDisplay is a child of seekBar (player.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar) and explicitly specified in the seekBar's options. How can I enable MouseTimeDisplay in seekBar? Thanks!

[An example](https://videojs.com/advanced/?video=disneys-oceans):

[image]

Comment: **(1)** How do you know it's _"...disabled by default"_? I mean, did you see such an `IF` statement in the VideoJS source code or something? If yes, then link to it and maybe there'll be a work-around to suggest. **(2)** Checking the component's [source code](https://gitlab.marum.de/apirek/video.js/-/blob/5.x/src/js/control-bar/progress-control/mouse-time-display.js) it seems the display only shows on mouse events, you'll have to edit such JS file with a new modified `handleMouseMove` function (eg: `handleTouchMove`) to update those variables based on touch position instead of mouse position.

Comment: **(3)** This other (more official?) [source code](https://docs.videojs.com/control-bar_progress-control_mouse-time-display.js.html) doesn't seem to define any mouse events, so looking at [source of component.js](https://docs.videojs.com/component.js.html) it seems there it has functions for handling touch position... Not obvious how anything is disabled by default as you find... **How to recreate your problem**?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your interest to my issue :) I've updated the post.